# How to add custom animation in SVG?

Tags: animation, svg

I want to rotate a image which is already built in SVG using animation without any online website, editor & without jQuery. I wanna do it custom.

Please help.

Comment: Use SMIL to animate it, or CSS animation if you prefer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### CSS animation

Raster images can be added inside SVG using the `<image>` tag

And use the usual CSS rules for animation

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="499.968" height="281.232" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
<defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        opacity: 0.96;
      }
  #disk{
 transform-origin: center center;
 transform-box: fill-box;
 animation: rotate_disk 10s linear forwards infinite;
  }

  @keyframes rotate_disk {
   100% {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
   }
  }
   
    </style>
  </defs>
<image x="293" y="75" width="1255" height="959" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/34irD.png"/>

<image id="disk" class="cls-1" x="515" y="165" width="815" height="815" xlink:href=" https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qas6q.png"/> 

<image id="scris" class="cls-1" x="363" y="740" width="1105" height="233" xlink:href=" https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCbha.png"/>
</svg>
```

### SVG animation

That there was no beating of a disk at animation of rotation it is necessary to precisely calculate the center of rotation

For calculation, the JS method `getBBox ()` is used

```
<script>
let BB = gr1.getBBox();

 console.log(BB.x + BB.width / 2);
 console.log(BB.y + BB.height / 2);
</script>
```

The obtained coordinates of the center of rotation: `x="925.5"` `y="572.5"`

Rotation Animation Formula:

```
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" dur="10s"
 values="0 922.5 572.5;360 922.5 572.5;"  />
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="499.968" height="281.232" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">

<image x="293" y="75" width="1255" height="959" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/34irD.png"/>
<g id="gr1">
<image id="disk" class="cls-1" x="515" y="165" width="815" height="815" xlink:href=" https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qas6q.png"/> 
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" dur="10s" values="0 922.5 572.5;360 922.5 572.5;" repeatCount="indefinite"  />
</g>
<image id="scris" class="cls-1" x="363" y="740" width="1105" height="233" xlink:href=" https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCbha.png"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this key framework will work on every browser?

Comment: @Rohit Saini Works in all modern browsers except IE11